# when crosscompiling this source why do I receive "No rule to make target" error on one host but not the other

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, compiling, make

I have the following linux kernel source repo cloned to a couple different hosts (my local machine and a Github Actions runner)

https://gitlab.conclusive.pl/devices/linux/-/tree/master

I'm using the [kstr-sama5d27 defconfig](https://gitlab.conclusive.pl/devices/linux/-/blob/master/arch/arm/configs/kstr_sama5d27_defconfig)

When building modules using `make modules -j4 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- LOCALVERSION=-kstr-sama5d27` I receive the following error on the GA host:

> make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/lib/firmware', needed by
> 'net/wireless/extra-certs.c'.  Stop.

whereas on my local machine building succeeds:

> GEN    net/wireless/extra-certs.c
> CC [M] net/wireless/extra-certs.o

I looked in net/wireless/Makefile but nothing within lead me to any ideas on how to troubleshoot this.

I figure the issue must be caused by differences in build environments.

Comment: Do you get that consistently (every time), and also without `-j4`?

Comment: Yes, consistently and without -j4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by [`CONFIG_CFG80211_EXTRA_REGDB_KEYDIR`](https://gitlab.conclusive.pl/devices/linux/-/blob/ad82d9390212f27e1c4ed9188e9a0e0b886e28ad/arch/arm/configs/kstr_sama5d27_defconfig#L203) which is set to `/lib/firmware`. When this configuration entry is not empty, it causes the build [to rely on `extra-certs.o`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19.10/source/net/wireless/Makefile#L24), which itself [depends on the directory given as the configuration value](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19.10/source/net/wireless/Makefile#L36). So the build succeeds on your own system, which has `/lib/firmware`, but fails on the GitHub action runner, which doesn’t.

If you don’t need to include extra certificates, you should override this configuration setting so that it ends up empty. That will allow the build to proceed without `/lib/firmware`.

If you do need extra certificates, place them in a directory next to your clone of the kernel repository (*e.g.* `firmware` next to `linux`) and change `CONFIG_CFG80211_EXTRA_REGDB_KEYDIR` to point to that (`../firmware`).

Answer (score 1):

Github Actions runners do not apparently include packaged firmware at `/lib/firmware` as is common for Linux distributions.

Stephen Kitt's answer is good for the case where you don't need the extra certificates. If you do need these certs then you'll need to obtain the firmware and point the config to them.

The firmware can be obtained by cloning
`git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git`

You may want place the firmware in a directory other than `/lib/firmware` to avoid overwriting existing firmware (not an issue it seems for Github Actions).

Comment: It would be better to change the directory to something else — by doing this you’ll overwrite your distribution’s packaged firmware.